# keep track of member variable access through instance

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I am trying to write some module which keep track of member variable access
through instance. 
1. is it possible to know member variable has access using instance at run time?
2. if yes, any design/pointer or idea

Purpose: I would like to write simple script which will read sample file(module) and member variable accessed by instance. So we can develop this as a part of debuging framework.

For example, if I write in main time.initial_time than my script able to detect that initial_time has been accessed by time Instance. it will be run at the run time. I mean, it will be part of existing flow

**Real Purpose**
The object contain 1000 value but some of them used by each module. if it's become debug framework so we can easily identify and print information of member variable access by instance. Yes each module create instance of data class. 
Sample file

```
"""testing pylint code"""
#!/usr/bin/env py
class Sample(object):
    """create sample class"""
    def __init__(self):
        """seting variable"""
        self.intial_time = 0

def main():
    """main functionality"""
    time = Sample()
    print time.initial_time

if __name__ == " __main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using descriptors.

Properties is a special case of descriptors but I believe they will not help you as much in this case.

Here is a descriptor that does exactly what you want:

```
from collections import defaultdict

class TrackedAttribute:

    def __init__(self, default_value):
        self.default = default_value
        # Dict mapping an instance to it's value
        self.instance_dict = defaultdict(lambda: default_value)

    def __get__(self, inst, owner):
        if inst is None:
            print("Accessed from class %r" % (owner,))
            return self.default
        print("Accessed from instance %r" % (inst,))
        return self.instance_dict[inst]

    def __set__(self, inst, value):
        print("Setting from instance %r" % (inst,))
        self.instance_dict[inst] = value


class Simple:
    time = TrackedAttribute(0)
```

Answer (score 0):

There may be a better answer more suitable to your specific needs (trying to identify unused variables), but Python has a `property` decorator that you could use:

```
class Sample(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self._initial_time = 0

    @property
    def initial_time(self):
        print('self.initial_time has been read')
        return self._initial_time

>>> print(Sample().initial_time)
self.initial_time has been read
0
>>>
```